# End of file of fstream object

Tags: c++, file

I came across this code which deals with a simple reading of a file and displaying its contents.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{   
    ...
    fstream file;
    file.open("TEXT.txt", ios::in);
    file.seekg(0);
    while(file) //does file returns 0 when eof is reached?
    {
        file.get(ch);
        cout << ch;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

*My question is how does `while (file)` realizes that the end of the file has been reached.*

Comment: Alex's Answer below true... For more information I would suggest looking at this tutorial on Stream States http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/135-stream-states-and-input-validation/

Comment: Watch out with the above code. `while (file)` enters the body of the loop if the stream is not in an error state, including end of file. This is good, but `file.get(ch);` may still fail and this result is not being tested. A better implementation would be `while(file.get(ch))` because that's going to test after trying to read.

Comment: @user4581301 The long explanation is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: Your loop is backwards, if `file.get` fails it goes on to `cout << ch` anyway

Comment: @M.M How do I put it then?

Comment: while ( file.get(ch) ) cout << ch;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out you should really use something like

```
char ch;
while (file.get(ch)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: although this helps improve the code, it doesn’t answer the question, both current answers combined would be perfect

Comment: Yeah it was originally intended to supplement Alex's answer as well as  πάντα ῥεῖ's suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

The stream implements a [boolean cast operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) that will return true if the stream is still good or false if there's an error or eof.

Comment: Is it equivalent to `while(fin.eof())` ?

Comment: @NooB No. `while(fin)` catches more error conditions than just EOF.

Comment: But I should add that, neither one does what you want. Both test for error before operating on the stream and potentially raising an error. Read the the link posted by @πάνταῥεῖ above for the straight dope.

Comment: @user4581301 great understood, also I know its a bit off topic but 1. Is it necessary to close a file explicitly like `fin.close();` for a small program and 2. Whether all files are automatically closed when a program terminates?

Comment: @NooB 1) Depends on when you want the file closed. If you want it closed immediately, call `close`; otherwise, just let the stream go out of scope and the destructor will take care of it for you. 2) two things help you here: The file stream destructor will fire under normal circumstances and close the file. If for some reason you don't call the destructor, called `exit` or `new`ed the stream and never called `delete` most likely, the system should take care of it for you.